# Overriding profile settings in Conan

Tags: python, conan

I have a special problem.
I'm creating a conan package for a Windows profile.
However, I need some packages which are uploaded to the Artifactory using a Linux profile.
This is fairly uncommon, as usually all components must be installed for the same profile. However, I can not change this as the Linux components are loaded by my software and transferred to a Linux computer where they are executed.

So is there a way to specify the profile for which I'd like to download a component from the artifactory inside a conan file?

Comment: You said "download", not "install", they are different commands, but I understand that you want to install a package.
Conan install a package based on your profile, thus, it doesn't matter if you are on Windows or Linux. You can override your settings directly by command arguments: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html#settings

Comment: Fixed it to install, sorry, used the wrong word.

I know I can change those by using the profiles or the command line. However I wanted to "fix" the settings inside my conanfile.py to not let the user change them.

Comment: Do you mean restrict settings from recipe? Yes, you can do it: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#settings But you will need to rebuild and reupload your package.

Comment: You can't do it. From inside the `conanfile.py` there is no way to override the settings that will be used for requirements. As you said, you will need to do it via a profile or command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't do it from inside the `conanfile.py`.

---

(As said in the question) You can do it using profiles or the command line. For example, if your project depends on `boost` and `zlib` and you need to mix different configurations you can do as follow:

- Using profiles:

  ```
  [settings]
  os=Linux  # This will apply by default to all libraries
  boost:os=Windows
  zlib:os=Android
  ...
  ```
- Command line:

  ```
  conan install <your/project> -s boost:os=Windows -s zlib:os=Android
  ```